# Joining multiples columns from more 5 tables

Tags: sql

I am trying to join `setid`(like a foreign key) which exist in all the tables in the query and also I am trying to join `lecid` which only exist in `lec` table and in `parktable` table as well as joining `weekid` in week and `parktime` table. I am also trying to join the `roomid` in `rooms` table and `parktable` table. All together `setid` is like a foreign key in all those tables. I am looking for a setid which is `48596`.

I have tried:

```
select t.slotid, r.number1, t.weekid, t.duration, p.name as DEPName, 
a.name  FROM parktime t

JOIN rooms k ON t.setid = k.setid

JOIN week r ON t.setid = r.setid

JOIN structure w ON t.setid = w.setid


FULL OUTER JOIN LEC p 
ON
t.LECID = p.LECID

FULL OUTER JOIN week r
ON t.weekid = r.weekid

FULL OUTER JOIN structure w 
ON

r.number1 = w.number1

FULL OUTER JOIN rooms k
on
k.roomid = t.roomid

WHERE t.setid  = '48596'
```

The problem is that this query takes too long to run and at the end of it, it doesn't come back with the result. `TEMP` error.

Is they a problem with the way I am joining it?

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @BillGregg it takes too long to run the query also after it crashed. I am using toad for oracle but if i try to  not join the `setid`(s) i get results but its over the amount i should be getting which in this case should be `2` rows

Comment: Why are you doing a join and a full outer join on rooms and structure when they don't appear to be used in the query, also you are doing the same two joins on week. Look into fixing those joins into one for each table (if the table is needed at all) will help performance.

Comment: @JoeW i cant see any out join on room and structure. I am only doing a join with room and parktime and also I am not repeating a join with week. where r u seeing this? I cant see it

Comment: The SQL you posted has them listed twice

Comment: @JoeW I am joining all the foregin keys in the first `JOIN` which is `setid` and in the `full outer join` i am joining second foreign keys which are in those tables. I said this in the question.

Comment: You should be able to join on both of those keys with one statement and not two.

Comment: can u show me how please. thanks

Comment: something like `JOIN rooms K ON k.setid = t.setid AND k.roomid = t.roomid`

Answer (score 1):

don't use join twice, as you have here:

```
FULL OUTER JOIN JOIN rooms k
```

If speed is your issue, you may want to put indexes on the cols that you are using to join and in the where clause: setid, number1, etc.

Comment: speed is important but getting a result back is also important at the moment i am not getting a result but an error.